# How to solve "Move target out of bounds" Selenium error?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to simulate clikcin on the "Load more listings" button on the "https://empireflippers.com/marketplace/" webpage untill the button no longer is. I tried the following code but it results in "Move target out bounds" error.

```
from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains




HOME_PAGE_URL = "https://empireflippers.com/marketplace/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(HOME_PAGE_URL)

while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Load More Listings')]")))
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        break
print("Complete")
time.sleep(10)
page_source = driver.page_source

driver.quit()
```

I'm expecting to retrieve the html code of the full web page without load more listings button.

Comment: The question wasn't answered.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the button that you are trying to click is not visible on the screen. You could try this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Load More Listings')]"))
```

To click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea *why*, but **trying to click twice** works for me. [I still get the same error if I try to click twice with `ActionChains`, and I'm not familiar enough with `ActionChains` to try to fix that; my usual approach is to use `.execute_script` to scroll to the element with JavaScript and then just apply `.click()` to the element, so that's what I've done below.]

```py
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(text(),'Load More Listings')]")))

        # ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);', element)
        try: element.click() # for some reason, the 1st click always fails
        except: element.click() # but after the 1st attempt, the 2nd click works...

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        break
```